# Is there a way to add a gradient without including an background-image in css?

Tags: html, css

I have a Wordpress-site where a background div is generated automatically with a background (set within customization for the theme used). The background-size is set to cover (by the theme).

I'm able to set the background-size to contain so proportions reflects correctly (with css), but then the whole image is smaller the the whole width of the browser when having a "desktop" resolution. This is how it's supposed to be!

The left and right part of this div I could easily set to a color (with background-color). But is it possible to "add a gradient" to an existing image div in css instead of a specific color?

something like

```
<div class="gradient" style="background:url('image.png') no-repeat;background-size:contain;">
```

To add a gradient is a no-brainer but then you include the background-image. Is there a way to add a gradient without including an background-image?

***I I do like this*** the current background-image gets **replaced** by the gradient image (and this is not what I want)

```
.header-homepage.custom-mobile-image {
    background-image: 
    linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(240,232,221,1) 0%, rgba(238,238,238,1) 43%) !important;        
}
```

I would want something like:

```
.div {background-gradient: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(240,232,221,1) 0%, rgba(238,238,238,1) 43%)
```

so the background-gradient covers the whole div and the actual background-image is scaled in the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got you right, you want to create a gradient overlay over the image? If this what you want, you can create a parent div which background is the image you want, and a child div which contains you text as well as the gradient background and decrease the opacity of the child div, so the image is visible. See this example:

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

.container {
  background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642634402-b0eb5e2eebc9") no-repeat center center/cover;
  color: white;
}

.child {
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, orange);
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">Content</div>
</div>
```

Also you can use rgba color values instead of red and orange for the gradient background where you can specify color opacity, but in this case you don't need to use opacity property in child div.

PS: using width and height prosperities is only for demonstration here. However, in your actual code, you don't need that because your divs' height will be determined by the content of the child div, as well as padding and borders.

Comment: Good answer! I would also recommend using the `::after` pseudo-selector instead of adding elements in the hierarchy if you only need to apply this effect and don't want to add any other content.

Comment: hmm I'm not able to add a parent div in this case without messing with the theme settings but using ::before or ::after might work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Gunther - To use ::after I would have to have  a parent that is relative to make it work? I mean like .header-homepage::after {background-image: linear-gradient(red, orange);} where the background-image is already set in header-homepage. I can not set "width and height of .header-homepage in the ::after ?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld I'll try to add another answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
I recommande using [this gradient generator](https://cssgradient.io/). Pretty straightforward.
[image: Example]

Comment: This is not a real answer for my question. Sorry :-) If I set this background as you suggest my current background-image would be overritten.

Answer (score 1):

As requested in comments here is how you can do it using only the `::after` pseudo-selector so you don't need to change the HTML structure. [Mohammad Essam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66496908/6398325) answers how you can do it with more flexibility.

```css
.header-homepage.custom-mobile-image {
    background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642634402-b0eb5e2eebc9") no-repeat center center/cover;
}

.header-homepage.custom-mobile-image::after {
  content: '';
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,255,1) 100%);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block; /* ::after defaults to inline */
  opacity: .7;
}

div {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-homepage custom-mobile-image"></div>
```